# Bibliography IEEE now shown some not shown at the end

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

Hi I have a list of bibtex references but some are not shown at the end in bibliography but only the number is shown. Such an example is for this citation:

```
@article{al hasan_dave_2017,
title={Triangle counting in large networks: a review},
volume={8},
url={https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/widm.1226},
DOI={10.1002/widm.1226},
number={2},
journal={Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
author={Al Hasan, Mohammad and Dave, Vachik S.},
year={2017},
pages={e1226}
},
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Choose bibliography keys without spaces, e.g. `al_hasan_dave_2017`. The `,` after the complete entry is also not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{al_hasan_dave_2017,
title={Triangle counting in large networks: a review},
volume={8},
url={https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/widm.1226},
DOI={10.1002/widm.1226},
number={2},
journal={Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
author={Al Hasan, Mohammad and Dave, Vachik S.},
year={2017},
pages={e1226}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{al_hasan_dave_2017}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

[image]